# geo tagging taking a lot of time in android app needs fix

Tags: android, windows, gps, location, computer-science

hi I use an app for geo tagging buildings .everyday I have to tag at least 150 buildings .and for each entry it takes at least 15 seconds .what is the reason for the delay and how can I fix it .its an android platform app.

is there any way to make it faster or tag as a group

or use the app in a tabs like setup in browser

I tried to change device and I also tried to fake the gps location so I can sit somewhere and type but it still takes a lot of time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The delay you are experiencing while geo-tagging buildings in the app could be due to various factors. Here are some possible reasons for the delay and potential solutions to make the process faster:

Network Connectivity: If the app requires a network connection to fetch location data or perform other tasks, a slow or unstable network can cause delays. Ensure that you have a stable internet connection while using the app.

Server Response Time: If the app sends data to a server for processing or storage, the server's response time can impact the overall speed. Check if the server infrastructure is optimized and capable of handling concurrent requests efficiently.

Data Processing: If the app performs complex calculations or data processing while tagging each building, it can lead to delays. Consider optimizing the algorithms and data processing steps to make them more efficient.

GPS Accuracy: GPS accuracy can affect the time it takes to tag each building. Make sure the GPS location data is accurate and the app is utilizing the location services effectively.

App Design and Code Optimization: The app's code and design could be causing performance issues. Review the codebase for any inefficiencies and optimize it to reduce processing time.

Bulk Tagging: If possible, consider adding a bulk tagging feature that allows you to tag multiple buildings at once. This way, you can significantly reduce the time spent on individual tagging.

Local Caching: Implement local caching of data to minimize the need for constant network requests, especially for static data that doesn't change frequently.

Background Processing: If some tasks can be performed in the background while you continue tagging other buildings, consider using background processing to improve overall efficiency.

Offline Mode: If network connectivity is an issue, consider adding an offline mode that allows you to continue tagging buildings and sync the data later when the connection is stable.

Hardware Limitations: Older devices or devices with limited processing power may also contribute to the delay. If possible, use a more powerful device to speed up the process.

App Updates: Check if there are any updates available for the app. Developers may have released performance improvements in newer versions.

It's important to note that some factors, such as server response time and GPS accuracy, may be beyond your control as an end-user. In such cases, you may want to reach out to the app's developer or support team to report the performance issues and inquire about potential solutions.

If the app doesn't offer bulk tagging or other performance-improving features, and the delay is consistently significant, you may consider looking for alternative apps that better meet your needs or discussing the issue with the app's developer to see if they can implement optimizations in future updates.